# AsyncRestTemplate config queue size

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a job that runs every hour, on 40core server, each job can have between 1 to 100 thousand tasks (need large queue), each task execute HTTP request when it finish, each task is critical which means it must run & complete.

Tasks can run asynchronously.

How do I config the number of threads in pool ? how do I config the **queue** size ?

in this test I'm trying to get my tasks rejected and flood my thread pool but instead i'm getting SocketTimeoutException

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOReactorException {
    String url = "http://internal.server:8001/get";
    int connectionTimeout = 3000;
    int soTimeout = 3000;
    int maxHttpConnections = 30;

    IOReactorConfig customIOReactorConfig = IOReactorConfig.custom()
            .setIoThreadCount(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())
            .setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeout)
            .setSoTimeout(soTimeout)
            .build();

    ConnectingIOReactor ioReactor = new DefaultConnectingIOReactor(customIOReactorConfig);

    PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager connManager = new PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager(ioReactor);
    connManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(maxHttpConnections);
    connManager.setMaxTotal(maxHttpConnections);
    CloseableHttpAsyncClient customHttpAsyncClient = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(connManager)
            .build();

    HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory asyncRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory(customHttpAsyncClient);
    AsyncRestTemplate asyncRestTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate(asyncRequestFactory);

    System.out.println("start");
    for (int i = 0; i < 30_000; i++) {
        asyncRestTemplate.execute(url, HttpMethod.GET, request -> logger.info("doWithRequest..."), response -> {
            logger.info("extractData...");
            return response.getStatusText();
        }).addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                logger.error("onFailure [{}] [{}]", ex.getMessage(), ex.getStackTrace()[0].toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String result) {
                logger.info("onSuccess");
            }
        });
    }
    System.out.println("end loop");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like:

```
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor poolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
poolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(100);
CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients
     .custom()
     .setThreadFactory(poolTaskExecutor).build();
```